# What will happen if I try to broadcast a transaction before the established locktime block height passed?

Tags: transactions, locktime, broadcast

If someone send me BTC with locktime and I accidentally try to broadcast transaction before the established block height passed, what will happen?

Am I still be able to broadcast it after the established block height passes or it will be stuck in network?

Answer (score 5):

The transaction will not be relayed across the network and it will simply be as if the transaction never happened in the first place.

Comment: Okay Andrew so the btc will just remain on sender wallet, right? (because they are blocked until specified block height mine but as I tried to broadcast that transaction before it happen transaction is invalid?) Thank you very much for help

Comment: Yes, the Bitcoin will not move.

Comment: This is of course assuming that your peers do actually discard the transaction (as Bitcoin Core does) and none of them hold onto it to rebroadcast it later when it becomes valid. It's unlikely, but you shouldn't assume it can't happen.